# SQL Server 2014 Express does not show newly created table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

[image]I created a table using the `create table` command but it does not show up in the object explorer. I have tried refreshing both the explorer and IntelliSense but it still does not show up. The table is present in the database I confirmed that by printing it out using the `select` command.

Comment: And you are expanding the correct database in the object explorer? Share the code you used to create the table, share the code you used to select from it, and share a screenshot of your object explorer.

Comment: I just have a single database on my machine apart from the default ones

Comment: See how it says 'master' on the bottom right? Expand System databases, master, and look for your table.

Comment: So how do I make a new table in my newly created database?

Comment: You should have done a `use DSTRAINING` before creating that table. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you created your table in the system `master` database instead of in your user defined database. There are a few things you can do:

1. At the top of your query, write `USE your_database_name`  That will set your connection to run your query against a specific database.
2. In SSMS, on the top left by default I think, there should be a white box with a dropdown arrow next to it. This is a list of all the databases in the instance you are currently connected to. Click yours, and run your table create.
3. Fully qualify your table name during the create as my_database_name.schema_here.table_name_here

Always look at the bottom of your SSMS window and confirm you are running queries in the correct instance (dev vs prod) and running them against the correct database.

```
USE database_name
GO 

CREATE TABLE dbo.my_new_table (ID INT)
GO
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE database1.dbo.test_user_table (ID INT)
GO
```